# converting a sparse dataframe to dense Dataframe in python efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Problem at hand, I have a dataframe which Looks like the one below:

**Input Dataframe:**

```
VEHICLE_HASH    LS_ID   UPPER_BOUND LS_RATIO

00061E31E25B36  PROMISELS103    2500.0  0.000684 

00061E31E25B36  PROMISELS103a   3000.0  0.002001 

00061E31E25B36  PROMISELS104    3500.0  0.004128 

0006254DB52066  PROMISELS104    4000.0  0.003216 

0006254DB52066  PROMISELS103    4500.0  0.001114 

0006254DB52066  PROMISELS105    5000.0  0.020767
```

This is a sample dataframe, the actual dataframe is of size `(53526122 x 4)`. Now i wanted to convert this dataframe to a OneHotEncoded Matrix with Features drawn from the string combined by `LS_ID` and `UPPER_BOUND` column. I was able to do one hot Encoding and convert the Matrix to a sparse Matrix and then i multiplied the sparse Matrix with the `LS_ratio` to get the resultant Input sparse Matrix for my xgboost classifier.

Now I want to convert the dataframe into this dense Format with an unique `HASH` per row with multiple column Features so i could do PCA with this data. But i get `out of memmory error`. Can this be done efficiently?

**Expected Output:**

```
HASH    PROMISELS103a_3000.0    PROMISELS103_2500.0 PROMISELS103_4500.0 PROMISELS104_3500.0 PROMISELS104_4000.0 PROMISELS105_5000.0

00061E31E25B36  0.002001        0.000684        0           0           0.004128        0                

0006254DB52066  0           0           0.001114        0.003216        0           0.020767
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to concatenate `LS_ID` and `UPPER_BOUND` columns with separator `'_'`, construct cross-tabulation (suppose all elements in constructed column and `'VEHICLE_HASH'` column is unique), and fill NaN values with zeros:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame() # here should be your initial dataframe
df['ID_AND_BOUND'] = df['LS_ID'] + '_' + df['UPPER_BOUND'].astype(str)
df_processed = pd.crosstab(index=df['VEHICLE_HASH'],
                           columns=df['ID_AND_BOUND'],
                           values=df['LS_RATIO'],
                           aggfunc=np.mean)
df_processed = df_processed.reset_index().fillna(0)
```